# MultinomialNB in python/pandas returns "objects are not aligned" error when predicting

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I've got a number of email subjects and performance ratings, and I want to use them to predict which subject lines will perform well. When I run my MultinomialNB, I get an "objects are not aligned" error. This is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

input=pd.read_csv('subject_tool_input_500.csv')
input.subject[input.subject.isnull()]=' '
good=np.asarray(input.unique_open_performance>0)
subjects=input.subject

classifier = MultinomialNB()
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(strip_accents='unicode')
counts=count_vectorizer.fit_transform(subjects)

classifier.fit(counts,good)
classifier.predict('test subject line')
```

This returns the following error.

```
>>> classifier.predict('test subject line')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 63, in predict
    jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 457, in _joint_log_likelihood
    return (safe_sparse_dot(X, self.feature_log_prob_.T)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 83, in safe_sparse_dot
    return np.dot(a, b)
ValueError: objects are not aligned
```

And this is the input that I am working with.

```
>>> subjects
0                         Thanksgiving Dinner Delivered
1           It's Not Too Late To Order for Thanksgiving
2               Stress Free Christmas Gift They'll Love
3     Save $10 On Christmas Gift Certificates - Inst...
4                    Need a Last Minute Christmas Gift?
5                           Give Mom Something Special!
6             Yummy Steaks For Dad - $15 Off Your Order
7     Order a romantic dinner today and get it by Va...
8     Taiyo Yuden Unveils Latest in SAW Filter and D...
9     Taiyo Yuden New Noise Reducing Ferrite Bead Ch...
10    Lithium Ion Capacitors Are Ultimate Replacemen...
11                                 Art Wolfe Newsletter
12                          Art Wolfe Seminar Tour 2014
13                     Art Wolfe Spring 2014 Newsletter
14                    Day of the Dead Sale at Art Wolfe
...
8797625                                 Подписка на рассылку
8797626                                 Подписка на рассылку
8797627                             Ramadan Mubarak from MFP
8797628                   Ramadan Mubarak from Insaan Relief
8797629              UK Muslims! You have one new message...
8797630    Open House - 1249 Los Robles Place, Pomona CA ...
8797631    Open House - Custom Built Home by Conrad Buff ...
8797632    Open House - Custom built by Buff, Smith & Hen...
8797633    Open House - Custom Built Home by Conrad Buff ...
8797634    Open House - Custom Built Home by Conrad Buff ...
8797635    Open House - Custom Built Home by Conrad Buff ...
8797636    Open House - Buff, Smith & Hensman custom buil...
8797637    RAMADAN PROGRAMS: Dars-e-Qur'an in Rawalpindi ...
8797638               Dars-e-Qur'an by Shaykh Hammad Mahmood
8797639               Dars-e-Qur'an by Shaykh Hammad Mahmood
Name: subject, Length: 8797640, dtype: object
>>> counts
<8797640x1172387 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 62516240 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
>>> good
array([ True, False,  True, ..., False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I was able get this done last week without pandas, but I have been trying to use dataframes to facilitate some of the later work I will be doing.

Comment: Does it work if you change this line: `subjects=input.subject` to `subjects=input.subject.values`?

Comment: Unfortunately, subjects=input.subjects.values does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. I need to get the counts for the subject line that I am attempting to predict as well, so the end should be something more like this.

```
subcount=count_vectorizer.transform(["this is a test subject"])
classifier.predict(subcount)
```

Hopefully people in the future can see this and not make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the tf-idf matrix not only the count

```
subcount=count_vectorizer.transform(["this is a test subject"])
tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(subcount)
classifier.predict(tfidf)
```